# Prove that for every prime $p$, there exists a solution to $(x^2-2)(x^2-6)(x^2-3) \equiv 0 \mod(p)$

Tags: number-theory

So far:
I know that$\mod(p)$ is a field thus one of the factors in the expression has to equal $0$ $\mod(p)$ for some $x$. However I just don't know where to continue from this point? How do I approach a congruency like this? Are there any general tips for problems like these?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I have updated the title, please make sure the correction is right.

Comment: Since $p$ is prime at least one of the factors is congruent to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either $\;2\;$ or $\;3\;$ is a quadratic residue modulo $\;p\;$... **or else** $\;2\cdot3=6\;$ is  ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ mod $p,\,$ if $\,2,3$ are not squares then their product $6$ is a square, since ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).